# Elasticseach type special @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, entity, spring-data-jpa

I have 1 index, 2 types. /spring-boot-1.3.3/

```
@Document(indexName = "main", type = "item")
@Entity
public class Item {
     private Long id;
     private String name;

     @ManyToOne
     private User owner;    
}
```

how can i ignore userData field only for type:"item"

```
@Document(indexName = "main", type = "user")
@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    //@JsonIgnore <- ignored for both types, if i add this annotation
    private UserData userData; // must be ignored for elastic type: "item"
}
```

Comment: I have one question. `@ManyToOne`: Does it make any sense in elasticsearch

Comment: I think no. It's for our primary DB